# replaceAll gives unexpected result

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String Str = new String("This is some text");
      System.out.println(Str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "."));
   }
}
```

It produces `This.is.some.text`. If I remove `^`, it the produces what I wanted : `.... .. .... ....`. What symbol `^` changes here? `^` means it's the beginning, but I still don't get why it produces the different result than having code without it. What am I missing?

Comment: [Bob's your uncle](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5B%5EA-Za-z0-9%5D). Start [learning regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). [Java specific](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: @HamZa Thanks, that are some great websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` has two different meaning in regular expressions. If it stands in the beginning of a regular expression (eg. `^[a-z]+$`), it means the beginning of a line. But if it stands in the beginning of a character class specifications (eg. `[^a-z]+`), it means negation.

Answer (score 2):

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` indicates  any character except `'A' to 'Z'`, `'a' to 'z'` and `'0' to '9'`

[image]

`[A-Za-z0-9]` indicates  any character of  `'A' to 'Z'`, `'a' to 'z'` and `'0' to '9'` 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`^` is used to *negate* the contents of the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

- `[abc]` means "one of the characters `a`, `b`, or `c`".
- `[^abc]` means "any character *except* `a`, `b`, or `c`".